# Is there an Erdős–Kac theorem for number of divisors?

Tags: nt.number-theory, probabilistic-number-theory

Erdős–Kac theorem gives average number of prime factors of an integer.

Is there a theorem which concerns average number of divisors of an integer?

Comment: For log of number of divisors, yea.

Comment: What is it? Can you post an answer? Reference would help too.

Comment: $(1/n)\sum_{m=1}^nd(m)=\log(n) + 2\gamma - 1  + O(n^{-1/2})$.

Comment: Also $ (1/n)\sum_{k=1}^nd^2(k)\sim\frac{1/\zeta(2)}{3!}(\log n)^3=\frac{1}{\pi^2}(\log n)^3.$ And in fact for the $r^{th}$ moment you get a $(\log n)^{2^r-1}$  with a well estimated numerical constant in front.

Comment: The average value (mean) of $d(n)$ is very different from the typical value (mode). As @GerryMyerson says, the average value of $d(m)$ for $m$ near $n$ is $\log(n)$. However, fix $\delta>0$. As Kodlu's answer below says, with probability $1$, we have $(1-\delta) \log \log n < \omega(n) < \Omega(n) < (1+\delta) \log \log n$, so $2^{(1-\delta) \log \log n} < d(n) < 2^{(1+\delta) \log \log n}$. A bit of algebra shows that $2^{(1 \pm \delta) \log \log n} = (\log n)^{(1 \pm \delta) (\log 2)}$, very different from the mean value $\log n$.

Answer (score 9):

Tenenbaum, *Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory*, Chapter III.4:

The frequencies of the number of distinct prime divisors $\omega(n)$ of $n$ obey:
$$
\frac{\#\{1\leq n \leq N:\omega(n)\leq \log_2 N+y \sqrt{\log_2 N}\}}{N}=\Phi(y)+
O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log_2 N}}\right),
$$
uniformly for $N\geq 2,$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}.$

The same holds for the total number of prime divisors $\Omega(n)$. Since the number of divisors $d(n)$ is sandwiched between $2^{\omega(n)}$ and $2^{\Omega(n)}$ the above relation also holds for its logarithm to the base 2. In particular:
$$
\frac{\#\{1\leq n \leq N:d(n)\leq (\log n)^{(\log 2)+y\frac{\log 2 }{\sqrt{\log \log n }}} \}}{N}=\Phi(y)+
O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log_2 N}}\right),
$$
*Notation:* $\log_2 N:=\log \log N.$